# Send data from Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit LE to Teensy 3.6

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, adafruit, teensy

I am trying to send data from Send data from an Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit LE to Teensy 3.6. I am trying to get data over Bluetooth to the Feather, then send that data to the Teensy. I have tried many different ways of Serial connections, but they have not worked. What is the best way to do this, and if it is Serial, how do I do this properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m case this helps anyone, I have figured it out. I ended up using the 31 and 32 pins on the Teensy 3.6 using the command “Serial4.begin”, then I used the RX TX pins on the adafruit board and the command “Serial1.begin”

The Serial numbers ie. “Serial4” are very important for this, and now it works perfectly.